# How to share the weights or parameters between encoders for ALBERT implementation, pytorch?

Tags: parameters, pytorch, bert-language-model

I've tried to implement the ALBERT model. I want to ask that how to share the weights or parameters between encoders for ALBERT implementation, in Pytorch?

```
    self.encoder = MySequential(
        *[EncoderBlock(
            hidden_size,
            num_head,
            self.use_leakyrelu,
            dropout_p,
          ) for _ in range(num_encoder)],
    )
```

Comment: Between encoders meaning between different encoder layers or between different model instances? Where is your current implementation?

Comment: I wrote the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define it yourself, i.e. something like

```py
class LayerRepeater(torch.nn.Module)
   def _init__(self, ...):
        self.layer = Layer(...)

   def forward(*inputs: Tensor, num_repeats: int) -> Tensor:
       output = inputs
       for _ in num_repeats:
           output = self.layer(output)
       return output
```

of course fixing the signatures, adding any extra fuzz you need and replacing `Layer` with the actual neural function that is being iterated.